# JPA - Count by Status of Admission Form (Status Type Enum)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, enums, spring-data-jpa

I have declared an `Enum` type StatusEnum as like:

```
public enum StatusEnum {
PENDING, ACCEPTED, REJECTED, IN_PROGRESS, COMPLETED
```

}

I am trying to get count of Admission form from their status, so i tried with query (in Repository):

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(a.status), a.status FROM AdmissionForms a GROUP BY a.status ORDER BY a.status ASC")
List<Object[]> admissionFormCountByStatus();
```

then i parsed it to List of DTO that I have specified (in service class),

```
List<Object[]> objects = admissionFormRepository.admissionFormCountByStatus();
    for (Object[] singleObject : objects ) {
        admissionFormStatusCountList.add(new AdmissionFormStatusCountResponseDTO(
            ((Number)singleObject[0]).intValue(), (StatusEnum)singleObject[1]));
    }
```

my DTO (AdmissionFormStatusCountResponseDTO)like:

```
public class AdmissionFormStatusCountResponseDTO {
private int count;
private StatusEnum status;

public AdmissionFormStatusCountResponseDTO(int count, StatusEnum status) {
    this.count = count;
    this.status = status;
  }
}
```

resource class:

```
@GetMapping("/workorders/countByStatus")
@Timed
public List<AdmissionFormStatusCountResponseDTO> admissionFormCountByStatus() {
    return admissionFormService.workorderCountByStatus();
}
```

results that I'm having is like:

```
[
  {
    "count": 6,
    "status": "ACCEPTED"
  },
  {
    "count": 2,
    "status": "COMPLETED"
  },
  {
    "count": 3,
    "status": "IN_PROGRESS"
  }
]
```

It's responding with count only if that status value is present but I also require count = 0 in result for status from Enum not assigned to any admission form yet.

Comment: You would need a table with all possible status values to be able to get that out of the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After preparing your `admissionFormStatusCountList` look manually which enums are missing in there and add them with value 0. You are not gonna get it out of the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I did the changes as below that i required.

I defined the `admissionFormStatusCountResponseDTO` like:

```
public class AdmissionFormStatusCountResponseDTO {

private Long accepted;
private Long completed;
private Long inProgress;
private Long pending;
private Long rejected;

public AdmissionFormStatusCountResponseDTO() {
}

public AdmissionFormStatusCountResponseDTO(Long accepted, Long completed, Long inProgress, Long pending, Long rejected) {
    this.accepted = accepted;
    this.completed = completed;
    this.inProgress = inProgress;
    this.pending = pending;
    this.rejected = rejected;
  }
//getters and setters
}
```

then update repository query using this DTO as:

```
@Query("select new com.purvik.app1.service.dto.AdmissionFormStatusCountResponseDTO(" +
    "SUM(CASE WHEN a.status='ACCEPTED' then 1 else 0 END)," +
    "SUM(CASE WHEN a.status='COMPLETED' then 1 else 0 END)," +
    "SUM(CASE WHEN a.status='IN_PROGRESS' then 1 else 0 END)," +
    "SUM(CASE WHEN a.status='PENDING' then 1 else 0 END)," +
    "SUM(CASE WHEN a.status='REJECTED' then 1 else 0 END)" +
    ") from AdmissionForm a")
AdmissionFormStatusCountResponseDTO admissionFormCountByStatusNew();
```

Service class:

```
public AdmissionFormStatusCountResponseDTO admissionFormCountByStatus(){
    log.debug("Request to get count of AdmissionForm by it's Status ");
    return admissionFormRepository.admissionFormCountByStatusNew();
}
```

Resource endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("/admissionForms/countByStatus")
@Timed
public AdmissionFormStatusCountResponseDTO admissionFormCountByStatus() {
    log.debug("get count of status from stored admissionForm");
    return admissionFormService.admissionFormCountByStatus();
}
```

response that now I've:

```
{
"accepted": 5,
"completed": 0,
"inProgress": 4,
"pending": 1,
"rejected": 1
}
```

I do not require to have all the statics defined in `Enum`. It's a constructor based JPQL query that bring expected results. Hope this will help others.

@Robert Niestroj is right if you want to have all the statics in response defined in your `Enum`. Just editing my code that help me out.